# lock the position of the report body in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I need to lock the position of the report's body in SSRS report (VS 2010) - Not changing the body width.

I have found a similar question on: [How to prevent autoresizing body in SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047786/how-to-prevent-autoresizing-body-in-ssrs-report), but the property consumeContainerWhitespace=true isn't a solution (The body width is not locked).

Comment: What is causing your report body to change width? Do you have a tablix with column groups, that causes the width of the report to grow? Maybe you can prevent the tablix from growing by putting suitable constraints on it?

Comment: I just put a new element on the form, and place it.
I can move it by mistake outside the border.
That may be tablix, or text.
Specially, I need to design my report, so many of the element shall be aligned to the left or right of the report (when I am adding a column to tablix, and it is out of size, body is changed).
I can manage, but this is annoying that the report is not locked (especially its width).

Comment: Now I understand. Unfortunately, it's not possible to lock the body width in the designer. You will simply have to take care not to place any elements that exceed the width, since this will always cause the report body to grow.

Comment: Thank you. Even little annoying, I can handle that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to lock the body width in the designer. You will simply have to take care not to place any elements that exceed the width, since this will always cause the report body to grow.

Nevertheless, SSRS use can use the property ConsumeContainerWhitespace, which can "lock" some region, whenever are declared.

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11153/consumecontainerwhitespace-property-to-remove-blank-space-in-ssrs-2008-report.aspx